# Авторская пунктуация своеобразна, - пойдёт?

Tags: пунктуация

> А ведь быть во Флоренции, думать о Флоренции, рассматривать Флоренцию
>   – значит помнить и о той зловещей фигуре, чья тень рассекла историю
>   города на две части: *до* и *после* – Савонарола.

Можно ли поставить более точные знаки? уйти от двух тире?

Comment: Со знаками вроде нормально, но мне не нравится сочетание "фигура, чья тень". Лучше "тень которой", поскольку "фигура" - абстракция, лишь косвенно выводящая на одушевлённую сущность. Это почти как "сапоги Савонаролы, _чьи тени_ накрывали следы мучеников".

Comment: Согласен с @Alex_ander по части замены "чья" на "которой".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддерживаю Мимоходова с его предложением перестроить фразу: убирается двоеточие, а вместе  с ним громоздкая конструкция становится проще, и падеж приложения в финале,конечно, предложный, это же согласованное приложение, несогласованное  только в кавычках.

*А ведь быть во Флоренции, думать о Флоренции, рассматривать Флоренцию – это значит помнить и о той зловещей фигуре, тень которой рассекла историю города на "до" и "после": Савонароле.*

А вот ко второму тире у меня претензий нет, нормально смотрится:

***А ведь быть во Флоренции, думать о Флоренции, рассматривать Флоренцию – значит помнить и о той зловещей фигуре, чья тень рассекла историю города на  "до" и "после", – Савонароле.***

Тире здесь больше на месте, оно выделяет фигуру Савонаролы. Два двоеточия не смотрятся, а два тире - нормально, они же далеко  друг от друга, смысл не затемняют, каждое выполняет свою роль.

И повтор Флоренции мне нравится - повтор заостряет внимание на значимости Флоренции для автора и читателя.

Comment: Видимо, и предлог полезно повторить после длинного представления персоны?

Comment: Абсолютно верно.

Comment: Добавьте второе *о* — и достигнете совершенства!  Как минимум, приблизитесь к нему  :))

Answer (score 0):

Согласен, пунктуация тяжеловата. Но, простите, мне грамматика не совсем понятна. Вы (или автор) Савонаролу принципиально не склоняете или у вас тут именительный падеж? Если второе, то откуда?

*Пить водку - значит помнить о самой важной в этом деле фигуре - собутыльнике*
*Спрашивать что-то на форуме - значит не доверять главному эксперту - себе.*

Ну никак там именительный не получается. Из-за этого, имхо, и все тараканы.
Ну и запятая, конечно, перед вторым тире напрашивается, чтобы закрыть придаточное.

***А ведь быть во Флоренции, думать о Флоренции, рассматривать Флоренцию – значит помнить и о той зловещей фигуре, чья тень рассекла историю города на две части: до и после, – Савонароле.***

Это по минимуму. Думаю, этим не надо ограничиваться, я бы, конечно фразу переделал.

Если попробовать второе тире убрать (хотя мне оно в тут глаз и не режет), то наверное, за счет двоеточия, которое перед "до и после" особо-то и не нужно.

*А ведь быть во Флоренции, думать о Флоренции, рассматривать Флоренцию – значит помнить и о той зловещей фигуре, тень которой рассекла историю города на две части, "до" и "после": Савонароле.*

Но тут не смею настаивать, пунктуация "авторская", то есть моя. 
И в довершении: вообще-то сам стиль оставляет желать. Чуть бы укоротить фразу.

(+)
О! придумал.

*А ведь быть во Флоренции, думать о Флоренции, рассматривать Флоренцию – это значит помнить и о той зловещей фигуре, тень которой рассекла историю города на "до" и "после": Савонароле.*

(++)
Еще бы от перечисления в начале как-то избавиться. Ну зачем там рерфен из Флоренций?!